# I want To get all the categoy 1 level

Tags: django, postgresql

```
class categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

I want To get all family parent with it for example when select parent categoy or child any live sub categoy

```
categories2 = categories.objects.get(id=2 )
categories2.children.all()
```

[image]

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you want, do you want all `sub-category-i`s? (with `i` any number) so the second "column" in your image?